# Sharing executeables from head node to compute nodes in a Unix HPC cluster

Tags: installation, cluster-computing, hpc

I am working with some CFD software on a Unix cluster, and the software is installed on the head node, but not as a module. Is there a way for me to share this software and its executable with the compute nodes so we can run jobs via slurm job scripts without having to reinstall this software to a different location on the head node?

So far I have been able to run a test case on the head node, so I know that the software is installed correctly and at least working on the head node. I have ssh to one of the compute nodes and searched for the executable there and not found a path where I have permission to run said executable.

Comment: Usually, HPC systems will have a file system that is shared across head nodes and compute nodes where you can install all the data (including executables/libraries) you need during execution. You should probably consult the documentation for the HPC service you are using or contact their service desk to ask where this is. Some batch submission systems (e.g. Slurm) can ship the executable as part of the parallel application launch but will need to make sure it has access to all the libraries it needs on compute nodes (assuming it is dynamically linked, this may work with a static executable)

Comment: Our cluster uses slurm to submit jobs. I have ssh to compute nodes and I do see some shared directories from the head node to the compute nodes. /usr/local/<some other directories> are shared to the compute nodes, but the one for this particular software /usr/local/CFD is not. Also not all of the subdirectories in /usr/local/... are shared. I have seen the mount command but I am not sure if that is a way to add that cfd subdirectory to automatically load it to the compute nodes.

Comment: I think this is a question you need to ask your local HPC system support team as it will be different on different HPC systems